# This code is a love calculator code how can I simplify the code?

Tags: python

First I want to state out that I am a middle school student. This code is a code that when a user inputs two names, it can see how many "true love" letters occur in the names and see how well are they going on. I want to know how can I simplify this code as below.
Would someone please help me?

```
def love_calculator():
    name1=str(input("please enter your name:"))
    name2=str(input("please enter your name:"))
    word1 = ['t', 'r', 'u', 'e']
    word2 = ['l','o','v','e']
    count1=0
    count2=0
    for i in name1:
        if i in word1:
            count1=count1+1
    for i in name2:
        if i in word1:
            count1=count1+1
    for i in name1:
        if i in word2:
            count2=count2+1
    for i in name2:
        if i in word2:
            count2=count2+1
    score= int(str(count1) + str(count2))
    if score<10 or score > 90:
        print("Your score is", score,  "you go together like coke and mentos.")
    elif score > 40 and score < 50:
        print("Your score is", score, "you are alright together.")
    else:
        print("your score is", score)


love_calculator()
```

Comment: No, this isn't a Angela Yu course.

Comment: You can combine word1 and word2 into a single variable since you are iterating through it for both the names.

Comment: You could merge the for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `count1` and `count2` as

```py
count1 = len([x for x in name1+name2 if x in "true"])
count2 = len([x for x in name1+name2 if x in "love"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def love_calculator():
    name1 = str(input("please enter your name:"))
    name2 = str(input("please enter your name:"))
    word1 = "true"
    word2 = "love"
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    combined_name = name1 + name2 
    for symbol in combined_name: 
        if symbol in word1: 
            count1 += 1 
        if symbol in word2: 
            count2 += 1
    score = int(str(count1) + str(count2))
    if score<10 or score > 90:
        print("Your score is", score,  "you go together like coke and mentos.")
    elif score > 40 and score < 50:
        print("Your score is", score, "you are alright together.")
    else:
        print("your score is", score)


love_calculator()
```

You can combine variables with two names into one variable. Then use just one for loop to pass through the two names. Also, do not forget about compliance with the rules of registration of PEP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ligthly shorter version

```
def love_calculator():
    name1=str(input("please enter your name:"))
    name2=str(input("please enter your name:"))
    word = 'truelov'
    count1=0
    count2=0
    
    count1 = sum( [1 for i in name1 if i in word] )
    count2 = sum( [1 for i in name2 if i in word] )
    
    score= int(str(count1) + str(count2))
    
    if score<10 or score > 90:
        print("Your score is", score,  "you go together like coke and mentos.")
        
    elif score > 40 and score < 50:
        print("Your score is", score, "you are alright together.")
        
    else:
        print("your score is", score)


love_calculator()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the same logic to calculate `count1` and `count2`, you could combine both names in the for-iteration

```
def love_calculator():
    name1 = str(input("please enter your name:"))
    name2 = str(input("please enter your name:"))
    word1, word2 = list('true'), list('love')
    count1, count2 = 0, 0
    for i in name1+name2:
        if i in word1:
            count1 += 1
    for i in name1+name2:
        if i in word2:
            count2 += 1
    score = int(str(count1) + str(count2))
    if score<10 or score>90:
        print("Your score is", score, "you go together like coke and mentos.")
    elif score>40 and score<50:
        print("Your score is", score, "you are alright together.")
    else:
        print("your score is", score)

love_calculator()
```